# Отличие в коде

Tags: php

хотел спросить есть отличии от такой коды

```
@header("Content-type: text/html;charset={$config['charset']}");
```

вместо этого?

```
header("Content-type: text/html;charset={$config['charset']}");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это элементарщина. 
@ подавляет вывод ошибки функции. Т.е. (чтобы не расписывать каноны), если символ @ стоит перед функцией, то ошибка, в случае если функция не сработает, не будет выведена.

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Первый заткнёт ошибку, если та произойдёт.